# Glia/Neuron ratio

Tags: neuroscience

Research seems to indicate that the further we go up the evolutionary ladder, the higher is the glia/neuron ratio, to the point that in humans glial cells conforms 90% of the brain.

Now, if the glia/neuron ratio is somehow related cogntive capabilities (considering it is higher up in the evolutionary ladder), and since the ideal of a brain made solely of glial cells and no neurons seems absurd, how high can the ratio glia/neuron get before it starts to be detrimental?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** The glia-to-neuron ratio is not sufficient in order to distinguish humans from other primates or mammals.

---

The figures of the glia-to-neuron ratio (GNR) being 10:1 come from old studies that either used guesstimates for the number of cells in either category or used methods that have since been improved. The newest estimates range about a 1:1 ratio for the whole brain as reviewed in [von Bartheld et al. 2016](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cne.24040/pdf). These authors comment on the evolution of the GNR:

> [Comparative studies have] shown that brain size does not scale universally
>   with neuron number, that different mammalian species
>   such as primates and rodents scale differently, that cell
>   numbers in cerebral cortex and cerebellum evolve in a
>   coordinated fashion, and that glia density and sizes
>   vary much less than neuronal density and sizes. The
>   GNR is highly conserved between structures and species,
>   pointing to an important and close regulation of
>   glia numbers (scaling) in response to, or regulated by,
>   neuron density and neuron sizes.

At least in the cortex, cell numbers and size are kept to a minimum, as they take valuable space from what really matters, dendrites and axons ([Chklovskii et al. 2004](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0896627302006797/1-s2.0-S0896627302006797-main.pdf?_tid=a8400e60-9f89-11e7-a80f-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1506080104_9048583deca6d07d23df0f1236c9da6e)).